# Python - Putting a loop into a list

Tags: python, list, loops

For my python program I am asked to calculate resistor values that the user inputs. In the program I am asked to demonstrate Data handling, Loops, Lists and Validation.

I have 7 resistor values to be inputted into the program. For each resistor input I have created a loop like so:

```
#Loop for Resistor 2:
while True :
    try:
        R2 = float(input( 'Resistor Value R2: ' ))
    except ValueError:
        print( 'Sorry, Invalid Input! Try Inputing A Number' )
        continue
    if R2 < 0 :
        print( 'Sorry, Invalid Input! Try A Positive Number ' )
        continue
    else :
        break
```

As I have 7 resistors I have 7 of these loops typed out for the program. This works completely fine. However I would like to have these all in a list. So for example, instead of writing this loop out 7 different times for 7 resistors, is to create a list and have this written once and repeat for all 7 inputs.

would anybody know how I could do this? I am quite new to python and quite confused.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a for loop instead and store values in a list:

```
resistor_values = []

for i in range(7): # loop will have 7 iterations(0 - 6)
    # write code to be executed 7 times
    while True: 
        # this while loop ends when valid value for R is input
        # and stored in resistors
        try:
            R = float(input( 'Resistor Value R: ' ))
        except ValueError:
            print( 'Sorry, Invalid Input! Try Inputing A Number' )
            continue

        if R < 0:
            print( 'Sorry, Invalid Input! Try A Positive Number ' )
            continue
        else:
            resistors_values.append(R) # this appends R to the end of the list
            break
```

This should result in a list containing your 7 resistor values

Comment: You have R2 in **if** statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
values = {}
for i in range(1, 8):
    while True:
        try:
            value = float(input( 'Resistor Value R%s: ' % i ))
        except ValueError:
            print( 'Sorry, Invalid Input! Try Inputing A Number' )
            continue
        if value < 0:
            print( 'Sorry, Invalid Input! Try A Positive Number ' )
            continue
        else:
            values['R%s' % i] = value
            break

print( values )

>>> {"R1": 470.0, "R2": 68.0, "R3": 1.6, ...}
```

Comment: He said a list, not a **dictionary**

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot!!

Comment: However I have another problem, 
in the program I have to calculate the total resistance in the circuit and have the formulas for that. This worked before I created the list.

RT1 = 1 / ((1/R2) + (1/R3))
RT2 = (RT1) + R4
RT3 = 1 / ((1/RT2) + (1/R5))
RT4 = (RT3) + R7
RT5 = 1 / ((1/RT4) + (1/R6))
RT6 = (RT5) + R1

that is the formulas for the resistances..
however when I run the program I get this message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/dylan/Desktop/test.py", line 22, in <module>
    RT1 = 1 / ((1/R2) + (1/R3))
NameError: name 'R2' is not defined

Comment: @DylanSwann this code doesn't meet your requirements for demonstrating lists

Comment: @Totem How do you know this?

Comment: @DylanSwann There aren't any lists in it, only a dictionary. You said "In the program I am asked to demonstrate Data handling, Loops, Lists and Validation" in your question.

Comment: @Totem so what do you think I should put in to demonstrate lists? I have no clue about this stuff and my tutor is useless and wont help

Comment: Well, if your tutor specified Lists as something you need to demonstrate, then using a list to store the values rather than a dictionary(as above). Every other answer on this page uses a list(this one uses a dictionary, unless the author edits their answer)

Comment: Google python lists and dicts and you'll learn the difference

Comment: I didn't use this one but thanks @Totem 
I have a few questions I think you could help me with, would you help a guy out?

Comment: @DylanSwann You are probably best posting them as questions on the site. I will help if I can then.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work. It pushes all the valid resistor in the list and after a certain number of valid resistors is inside it will break.

```
resistors = []
while len(resistors) < 7:
    try:
        R = float(input( 'Resistor Value R: ' ))
    except ValueError:
        print( 'Sorry, Invalid Input! Try Inputing A Number' )
        continue
    if R < 0 :
        print( 'Sorry, Invalid Input! Try A Positive Number ' )
        continue
    else:
       resistors.append(R)
```

Answer (score 0):

You do a for loop from 1 to 7 repeating the code in question with the addition of parameterizing the prompt to the index of the resistor in question.

```
def ask_for_input(resistor_number):
    while True :
        input_string = input('Resistence value for Resistor {0}: '.format(resistor_number))
        try:
            resistence_value = float(input_string)
        except ValueError:
            print( 'Sorry, Invalid Input! Try Inputing A Number' )
            continue
        if resistence_value < 0 :
            print( 'Sorry, Invalid Input! Try A Positive Number ' )
            continue
        else :
            return resistence_value

resistences = []
for index in range(1, 8):
    resistences.append(ask_for_input(index))

print resistences
```

Comment: This works 100%, however I have to then calculate the total resistance in the circuit. To do this I have a number of Calculations:

RT1 = 1 / ((1/R2) + (1/R3))
RT2 = (RT1) + R4
RT3 = 1 / ((1/RT2) + (1/R5))
RT4 = (RT3) + R7
RT5 = 1 / ((1/RT4) + (1/R6))
RT6 = (RT5) + R1

however the R1-R7 are not defined, how do I fix this to correspond with your code

Comment: @totem could you help with this?